# Is it possible change the default Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to change the default Firebase Realtime database for an existing Firebase project in any way?

The [CLI commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli?hl=da#rtdb-commands) doesn't have this option neither does the [web console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/).

Is it possible somehow to change the default Firebase Realtime database?

Comment: Are you referring to the location of the database?

Comment: It's possible to create a new databases with an alternative location. I'm asking if it's possible to set the new database as default. The reason why I'm asking is because I want to change the location of the default DB.

Comment: Are you using one of the mobile SDKs or the Admin?

Comment: All options are open, I can be using all of the above. I'm asking if its possible somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the default Firebase Realtime database for an existing Firebase project in any way?

No, there is not. You cannot change the default location once it was created.

> It's possible to create a new database with an alternative location?

Yes, it is possible. You can create a new instance of the Realtime Database that can be located in a totally different location than the default one. According to the official documentation of the [Realtime Database locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations):

> If you create a new Realtime Database instance, you're prompted to select the location of the instance in the Firebase console workflow. **Each Realtime Database instance in your project can be located in a different location.** The currently supported locations for Realtime Database instances are listed below along with their associated database URL schemes.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to change the default realtime database instance as far as I know. You cannot even delete the default instance (it can be disabled though). If you are trying to set another instance as default, you can just export the data as JSON and then import it in the default database instance.