# Google Firebase - GDPR - EU

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

1. Is it possible to change the Database location from `United States (us-central1)` to EU? Or do I have to create a new project and migrate data?
2. When the database location is in EU, will all data be contained in EU? Or will data still be sendt to the US. I was told that even though the database location is in the EU, the Firebase code still is executed in the US, witch means that the data is sendt to the US.

My Default GCP resource location is eur3 (europe-west)
The  Database location: United States (us-central1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the Database location from United States (us-central1) to EU? Or do I have to create a new project and migrate data?

No, it's not possible, but there is a workaround. You can create a new instance of the Realtime Database that can be located in a totally different location than the default United States (us-central1) one.

- [Is it possible change the default Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68789067/is-it-possible-change-the-default-firebase-realtime-database/68828095#68828095)

> When the database location is in the EU, will all data be contained in the EU? Or will data still be sent to the US?

According to the official documentation regarding [Realtime Database locations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations), if you choose to store the data in `europe-west1`, the country that is associated with this region is Belgium. No data is sent to the US unless to choose that.

Answer (score 1):

After you set your project's default GCP resource location, you cannot change it.

It is currently not possible to move a database instance to another region. You'll have to add a new instance to the same project and create that in the region.